# In Mongo custom serialization how do I get the objectId?

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

In Mongo custom serialization how do I get the objectId?

I have implemented IBsonSerializer and my data is showing up in the database the way I want it. However my ObjectId is now empty (000000000000000000000000) after I insert into the collection where before it had the ObjectId like 5236ea9949444a06d7f50012. I can see the ObjectId is in the database so I know it is there, it is just not being populated to my C# object after I insert into the collection.

Here is my code:

```
public class EvaluationResultMongoSerializer : IBsonSerializer
{

    public object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IBsonSerializationOptions GetDefaultSerializationOptions()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {

        EvaluationResult er = (EvaluationResult)value;
        bsonWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        bsonWriter.WriteDouble("Duration", er.DurationInSeconds);
        bsonWriter.WriteDateTime("Start", BsonUtils.ToMillisecondsSinceEpoch(er.startTime));
        bsonWriter.WriteDateTime("End", BsonUtils.ToMillisecondsSinceEpoch(er.endTime));
        bsonWriter.WriteString("Result", er.Result.ValueAsString);
        bsonWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

I register the mapping like this:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(
            typeof(EvaluationResult),
            new EvaluationResultMongoSerializer()
        );
```

and I'm not registering any class maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I did two things. I may have only needed to do the second.

1. Implemented IBsonIdProvider - this has GetDocumentId and SetDocumentId - not sure I NEEDED to do this.
2. In my serialize method serialize the objectid with the element name "_id" - definitely needed to do this.

Here is my code:

```
public class EvaluationResultMongoSerializer : IBsonSerializer, IBsonIdProvider 
{

    public object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        EvaluationResult er = new EvaluationResult();
        bsonReader.ReadStartDocument();
        er.Id = bsonReader.ReadObjectId();
        er.DurationInSeconds = bsonReader.ReadDouble();
        er.startTime = BsonUtils.ToDateTimeFromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(bsonReader.ReadDateTime());
        er.endTime = BsonUtils.ToDateTimeFromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(bsonReader.ReadDateTime());
        er.Result = EvaluationStatus.Parse(bsonReader.ReadString());
        er.JSON = bsonReader.ReadString();
        bsonReader.ReadEndDocument();
        return er;
    }

    public IBsonSerializationOptions GetDefaultSerializationOptions()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        EvaluationResult er = (EvaluationResult)value;

        bsonWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        bsonWriter.WriteObjectId("_id", er.Id);
        bsonWriter.WriteDouble("Duration", er.DurationInSeconds);
        bsonWriter.WriteDateTime("Start", BsonUtils.ToMillisecondsSinceEpoch(er.startTime));
        bsonWriter.WriteDateTime("End", BsonUtils.ToMillisecondsSinceEpoch(er.endTime));
        bsonWriter.WriteString("Result", er.Result.ValueAsString);
        bsonWriter.WriteString("JSON", er.JSON);
        bsonWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    public bool GetDocumentId(object document, out object id, out Type idNominalType, out IIdGenerator idGenerator)
    {
        idNominalType = typeof(ObjectId);
        idGenerator = ObjectIdGenerator.Instance;

        var mongoDocument = document as EvaluationResult;
        if (mongoDocument == null)
        {
            id = null;
            return false;
        }

        id = mongoDocument.Id;
        return true;
    }

    public void SetDocumentId(object document, object id)
    {
        var mongoDocument = document as EvaluationResult;
        if (mongoDocument != null)
        {
            mongoDocument.Id = (ObjectId)id;
        }
    }
}
```